# Inner product space two subspaces proofing question

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The question is as follows:

Let $V$ be an inner product space of dimension $n$, and let $U$ and $W$ be two $m$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Assume there is some nonzero vector $v$ in $U$, such 
    that $v$ is orthogonal to $W$. (that is $\langle v,w\rangle =0$ for all $w$ in $W$). 
    Prove that $w$ is orthogonal to $U$ for some nonzero $w$ in $W$.

So I got a hint that it helps to fix a basis $B$ and $A$ for $V$ and $W$ and write 
   $v$ as a linear combination of it. Then
   explore what it means for $v$ to be perpendicular to every vector in $W$.

This is what I have done so far:
Let $B= \{b_1,...,b_m\}$ and $A = \{a_1,...,a_m\}$ be basis for $U$ and $W$.
I found an $m\times m$ matrix $M = [\langle b_i,a_j\rangle]$ such that $\langle v,w \rangle = [w]_A M [v]_B = 0$ for any $w$, so $[v]_B$ is in the nullspace of $M$. From here, I don't know how to keep going.

Can someone kindly suggest? Thanks, and sorry for the messy notation.

Comment: Sorry the material has some typo, just fixed it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Hint: row rank = column rank.

Comment: so basically we have nullity of M = nullity of M^T, that is there exists some w s.t. M^T*w_A = 0. Am I right?

Comment: Right. Now interpret this in terms of inner products of $w$ with the basis of $U$.

Comment: Thank you. Your hint is greatly appreciated and so useful!

Comment: Sounds like you can write up your own answer to the question now.

Answer (score 5):

We wish to show that $W \cap U^\perp$ is nontrivial. We have
\begin{align}
\dim(W \cap U^\perp) &= \dim V - \dim\big((W \cap U^\perp)^\perp\big) \\
&= \dim V - \dim (W^\perp + U) \\
&= \dim V - \dim (W^\perp) - \dim U + \dim(W^\perp \cap U)\\
&\ge \dim W - \dim U + 1\\
&= 1
\end{align}

since $v \in W^\perp \cap U$, $v \ne 0$ so $\dim(W^\perp \cap U) \ge 1$.

We conclude $\dim(W\cap U^\perp) \ge 1$ so there exists $w \in W \cap U^\perp$, $w \ne 0$.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. :-P

Comment: This is a nice one! Thank you so much. But if I wanna use the hint mentioned in the question, I am still confused. Anyway, this is a better solution!